# Best way to not DRY the same private method in several EJBs?

Tags: java, ejb, dry

I have some stateless EJBs and all of them have an equal private method:

```
private User getLoggedinUser() {
  String username = sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
  return entityManager.createNamedQuery(User.findByUsername, User.class)
        .setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
}
```

What is the best way to avoid this code duplication? Outsource `getLoggedinUser()` into a further bean and inject this in my existing EJBs?

Comment: This depends on a lot of how your program is structured, but my first inclination would be to either make `getLoggedInUser()` a static method and pass in the `entityManager` or, as you said, make it its own service bean if your container supports properly-scoped `PersistenceContext` proxies.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule the EJBs should be **highly** cohesive and for SOA architectures tends to work like Facades (Service Facades). So, this depends on  EJB responsibilities. If is an EJB that has lots of helper methods you could extract them to a specialized Service (remember that CDI supports inheritance model, could be useful to group some helpers). I prefer to avoid pass on the entityManager across methods, mainly, because loads your methods with parameters (to less the better), at the end the persistence context is shared across all the EJBs and Services that works in the same transaction.

Another way is use an Interceptor, the idea is based on Decorator pattern, but Interceptors implies a little of *magic*, so, use it only if you want to accomplish a precondition or a cross cutting concern.